# Define/change Kubernetes SSH key file name in a YAML

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, kubernetes-secrets

I have a secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-ssh-auth
type: kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
data:
  ssh-privatekey: |
          SEVMTE9PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PCg==
```

and deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: secret-ssh-auth
            mountPath: /root/.ssh
      volumes:
      - name: secret-ssh-auth
        secret:
          secretName: secret-ssh-auth
          defaultMode: 0400
```

It creates a file with this path `/root/.ssh/ssh-privatekey` while I want to have `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` name instead.

I know we can solve it by running a kubectl command, but I want to handle it inside the YAML file.
So, how to do that by the YAML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Kubernetes documentation the `ssh-privatekey` key is mandatory, in this case, you can leave it empty via `stringData` key, then define another one by `data` key like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-ssh-auth
type: kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
stringData:
  ssh-privatekey: |
          -
data:
   id_rsa: |
          SEVMTE9PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PCg==
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, and revolved it by simply defining the spec.volumes like this, which renames the `key` with  the `path` value:

```
  volumes:
    - name: privatekey
      secret:
        secretName: private-key
        items:
          - key: ssh-privatekey
            path: id_rsa
        defaultMode: 384
```

then refer it inside the container definition:

```
  containers:
    - name: xxx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: privatekey
          mountPath: /path/to/.ssh
```